# Unable to get params in @Around notation in my grails project

Tags: grails, groovy, aop, aspectj

so it is the code from previuos question...nd its works perfectly with annotations but now i m confused with one thing

```
package com.app.aspects

@Aspect
@Component("loggingAspect")
class LoggingAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.app.annotations.LogAction)")
    public void logParams() {}

    @Before("logParams()")
    public void loggingParams() {
        println "Before Params"
    }

    @After("logParams()")
    public void loggingParamsAfter() {
        println "After Params"
    }
}
```

now i added this code for intercepting params

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.app.annotations.ActionParams)")
public void methodPointcut() {}

@Around("methodPointcut()")
public Object methodPointcutCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("actionParams is being called");
    println "Start--"
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs()
    if(args.length > 0) {
        System.out.print("Arguments passed:");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Arg"+(i+1)+":"+args[i]);
        }
    }
    println "End--"
    return joinPoint.proceed(args);
}
```

this method is executing and printing

```
Start--
End--
```

but it is not printing the arguments , i dont know why this is happening as this works when i use simply around with execution

```
@Around("execution(* com.itexchangeweb.*.*(..)) && args(java.lang.String)")
public Object methodPointcutCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("actionParams is being called");
    println "Start--"
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs()
    if(args.length>0){
        System.out.print("Arguments passed:");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Arg"+(i+1)+":"+args[i]);
        }
    }
    println "End--"
    return joinPoint.proceed(args);
}
```

I try pointcut with

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.app.annotations.ActionParams) && args(java.lang.String)")
```

but its not working what's the issue with annotation and arguments

Comment: I have edited your question because the code formatting was all messed up, making the code unreadable.

Comment: Can you please update the question? I would like to see both the annotation source code (including package declaration) as well as an annotated method (including package and class name information) which you intend to intercept.